# MySQL copy table to another database (not the same network)- backup?

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I have a working database - and I want to copy all its data (or even just 1 table from it) and create a backup on disk and also create a "backup" database on another location (not the same computer). The other computer is not connected to the internet

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` to create dump of you Database. Which will be in `<name>.sql` format.

Then restore it in another system.

Reference: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump

Comment: sorry , but I guess I'm missing something ..... how do I do this using MySQL WorkBench?    Thanks,

Comment: There are only 4 commands. You can easily do this using command line.
In MySql workbench there is option of `import and export`. Try that. 
Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-enterprise-backup-backup-recovery.html

Comment: Thanks  , I did a simple export\import for tha table I wanted.... BTW can I do the same thing to a whole DB? All Table? and not jsut 1 table inside?

Comment: Yes of course. There should be select all option which will take dump of whole database.

Comment: Ok , I will try - Thank you